# why badPwdCount, badPwdCount, Last-Logon, and Last-Logoff are nit replicated

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I was searched many website to find the reason for not replicating some Attributes in AD( badPwdCount, Last-Logon, and Last-Logoff).if anyone knows the reason, please explain me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of these attributes as "local attributes" which are specific to each domain controller, and therefore not replicated across the domain. There are several other non-replicated attributes in addition to these 3. While Microsoft hasn't given specific reasons, one reason would be the large increase in the amount of traffic it would cause.

Consider that it can be helpful to know exactly which domain controller a user has authenticated against, and having these attributes not replicate can assist with that.